# seeking clarity regarding std::cout and std::endl

Tags: c++, buffer, cout, flush, endl

I am trying to get a better understanding of what happens to the `buffer` when we do not use `std::endl` after `std::cout`.

Let us consider the following piece of C++ code -

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

As per my understanding, `std::cout`  would add the string `Hello World!` to the `buffer`. If we do not add `std::endl` at the end of the code - `std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;` , should we or should we not expect `Hello World!` to be printed as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since all streams are flushed at their destructors, and global `std::cout` object will be destructed upon program exit, the string will be printed.

Note, however, that there will be no new line character in the end of the printed string, so console prompt would look unusual (and ugly) with your regular prompt immediately following `Hello World!`.

Comment: let's say we add `while(true);` after `std::cout <<"Hello World!";`.

Would `Hello World!` be printed on the terminal in this case?

Comment: @skpro19 likely no.

Comment: But that's not guaranteed. Is it?

Comment: @skpro19 no, it is not guaranteed, but I would be surprised to see it not happening.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the ugliness SergeyA mentioned but still avoid typing in "<< std::endl" we usually write

```
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

the "\n" forcing a new line after the output.